# Select a button inside a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is the GSP code where in which I am making a call to the Java Script function.

```
<div class="approval-container row">    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn byop-yes-button" onclick="test1($(this))">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn byop-no-button" onclick="test2($(this))">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="approval-email-container row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" name="button1" disabled="true" class="btn email-yes-button1" onclick="test3($(this))">ABC</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code logic:

```
function test1(button) {

        $(button).closest('.approval-container').find('.approval-email-container button[name="button1"]').addClass('btn-default');

}
```

Searched for the similar posts but it is not working for me. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `function test1(button) { .done(function(data)`...What is it? What does `.done` belong to? It is an incorrect syntax and you would know that if you simply opened a console and noticed an error.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev its part of Ajax call. I have pasted only the code which has the actual logic.

Comment: @SantoshAnantharamaiah It is pretty not obvious. And it definitely doesn't improve readability :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I completely agree with you, but it is part of our project. Hope you understand my concern.

Comment: @SantoshAnantharamaiah You're referencing an element in the `.closest()` selector that isn't in the HTML of your question. That, at the very least, needs to be included.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Please look into the latest code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `onclick="test1($(this))"`, you send already an object. 
You can try just this:

```js
function test1(button) {
        button.addClass('btn-default');
        button.closest('.approval-container').find('.email-yes-button'+(button.index()+1)).addClass('btn-default')
    }
```

```css
.btn-default{
    width:500px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="approval-container row">    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn byop-yes-button" onclick="test1($(this))">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn byop-no-button" onclick="test2($(this))">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="approval-email-container row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" name="button1" disabled="true" class="btn email-yes-button1" onclick="test3($(this))">ABC</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.I want the same effect to happen on button ABC once we click on Yes.

Comment: Thanks again for the update. I am worried about the current button group. Since in the present context, we have multiple button groups. How can I target the current button group.

Comment: i not understand all. You want addclass on all your group button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94914/discussion-between-p-frank-and-santosh-anantharamaiah).

Comment: Yes I resolved in another way. Thanks a lot for all your help. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: there is no **`input`** with name `button1` in your HTML. You have a **`button`**:

```
<button type="button" id="button1" name="button1" disabled="true" class="btn email-yes-button1" onclick="test3($(this))">ABC</button>
```

Change this code

```
$(button)
    .closest('.approval-container')
    .find('.approval-email-container input[name="button1"]')
    .addClass('btn-default');
```

to

```
$(button)
    .closest('.approval-container')
    .find('.approval-email-container button[name="button1"]')
    .addClass('btn-default');
```

By the way, this `button` has `id`, which is guaranteed to be unique (it **must** be), and you can easily replace your code with:

```
$('#button1').addClass('btn-default');
```

Comment: Even after changing from input to button its not working. And we are generating multiple buttons under different div's with same id so I think the second solution will not work.

Comment: ID's must be unique in the document. Jquery will only return the 1st ID it finds as it is only expecting a single result.

Comment: Exactly that's why I would like to handle this case without using ID.

Comment: @SantoshAnantharamaiah You definitely **shoudn't** generate divs with the same ID. It is simply not a correct HTML and doesn't make sense. Please, read [documentations](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).

Comment: @Yeldar - And one more important point is, I will not be adding ID in the production code, since for testing I have added ID in the development(local) code.

Comment: @SantoshAnantharamaiah Please, reproduce this problem at JSFiddle. When I implement it, it does work.

Comment: I have implemented the same solution you provided, but its not working for me. Could you please have a look into the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If Id's is not good Idea for you then try Class and [**Try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/eky3ys6z/) way.

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn byop-yes-button">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn byop-no-button" onclick="test2($(this))">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="approval-email-container row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="button1" name="button1" disabled="true" class="btn email-yes-button1" onclick="test3($(this))">ABC</button>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>

    <script>
    $('.byop-yes-button').on('click',function() { 
       //if you are worried about current element 
       //you can use $(this) here instead  of parameter in a function.
       //which is a usual good practice to work with jquery.
     $('.approval-email-container').find('button[name="button1"]').addClass('btn-default');
       })
  </script>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the changes which has to be done for targetting the current element, which is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the selector attribute documentation [attribute_selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

I think that the following code can help you, but try to describe better what you need.

Javascript:

```
// if realy needs to be the clossest approval-container. All buttons inside
function test11(button) {
    button.closest('.approval-container').find('.approval-email-container button[name*="button"]').addClass('btn-default');
}
function test22(button) {
    button.closest('.approval-container').find('.approval-email-container button[name*="button"]').removeClass('btn-default');
}

//if it will be just one approval-container. All buttons inside
function test1(button) {
    $('.approval-email-container button[name*="button"]').addClass('btn-default');
}
function test2(button) {
    $('.approval-email-container button[name*="button"]').removeClass('btn-default');
}

//Toggle option. All buttons inside
function test(button){
    var elem = $('.approval-email-container button[name*="button"]');
    if(elem.hasClass('btn-default')) elem.removeClass('btn-default');
    else elem.addClass('btn-default');
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="approval-container row">    
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn byop-yes-button" onclick="test1($(this));">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn byop-no-button" onclick="test2($(this))">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn byop-yes-button" onclick="test11($(this));">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn byop-no-button" onclick="test22($(this))">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn byop-yes-button" onclick="test($(this));">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn byop-no-button" onclick="test($(this))">No</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="approval-email-container row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" name="button1" disabled="true" class="btn email-yes-button1" onclick="test3($(this))">ABC</button>
        </div>
         <button type="button" name="button2" disabled="true" class="btn email-yes-button1" onclick="test3($(this))">ABC</button>
        </div>
     <button type="button" name="button3" disabled="true" class="btn email-yes-button1" onclick="test3($(this))">ABC</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```